# MouseDown Event for Button

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

In Visual Studio 2008 C# application I have the control with the button.  I try to get MouseDown event for button (the event is defined in Control class that Button inherits from).
if I write this:

```
this.button1.MouseDown += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button_MouseDown);
```

it compiles but the even is not raised.

The same will work for the whole panel itself

```
this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button_MouseDown);
```

Why I can't get that event work in derived class?  Is there any way to make it work?

This is my InitializeComponent() method:

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 140);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 39);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseDown);
        // 
        // MopilStatsPanel
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "MopilStatsPanel";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(286, 337);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

Comment: Add related code to the question. Where do you assign handlers to the event?

Comment: FYI, `button1.MouseDown += Button_MouseDown`.

Comment: Do you have anything overlaying that button that could be trapping the event? Another panel perhaps?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It works in my example...

Comment: No it's just user control and one button in it.  when I create event for the whole control it works (except if I click on button).  Creating event for button doesn't do anything

Comment: Works fine for me as well. You just have a form with a single button in it, correct?

Comment: "if I write this" - and where do you write it? Could you post the whole control here?

Comment: Note that the Button class has a Click event which is usually preferable to the MouseDown event.  If you use the MouseDown event then users will not be able to trigger the button via keyboard input.

Comment: I posted the full initializecomponent() method in my original post.  The event this.button1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseDown); has no effect.  If I do the same but for main panel instead of button the even is triggered.  Also the Click event is on mouseup event.  I need mousedown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use *MouseButtonEventHandler* instead of just *MouseEventHandler*:

```
this.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(this.Button_MouseDown);
```